# Find first cell in a row that contains a number?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I'm working in Excel with an exported table such as this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   |        A          |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |   G   |  H  |     I     |
|---|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|-----------|
| 1 |      Domain       | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | Start | End |   Change  |
|---|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|-----------|
| 2 | www.mydomain1.com |     |   1 |   4 |   3 |   1 |     1 |   1 |         0 |
|---|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|-----------|
| 3 | www.mydomain2.com |   2 |   4 |  12 |  18 |  23 |     2 |  23 |        21 |
|---|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|-----------|
| 4 | www.mydomain3.com |     |     |  14 |  12 |     |    14 | xxx | NOT FOUND |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I'm trying to compare the current state (last cell) to the original cell (first cell with a value).

In column I, I have the formula `=IF(G2 = "xxx", "NOT FOUND", IF(H2 = "xxx", "NOT FOUND", H2 - G2))`

In column H, I have the formula `=IF(F2 = "", "xxx", F2)`

In column G, I need to find the first cell with a number.  If there isn't one in that range, I need G to be "xxx".  I suppose I only need to check for the first cell in the range (B2 to F2) that contains a value, not just a number.  I tried using an Index and Match combo, but I couldn't quite understand it.

Comment: +1 for the well formatted table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula (in `$G$2` and filled down) should do the trick:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"xxx",INDEX(B2:E2,,COUNTBLANK(B2:F2)+1))
```

Note that this will only work if there are no other blank cells in between the first and last entries.

***update:*** Here is a more versatile option [from the Mr.Excel forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=349154):

```
=INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0))
```

This one has to be entered as an "array formula" which means you must press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER after pasting in the formula.

***response to comment:***

> It works great, except that if all cells are empty on a row, it returns #N/A. So, I changed the formula slightly to include an IsNA() condition:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0))), "xxx",
    INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0)))
```

Rather than duplicate the whole formula, you could do the following:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(B2:F2)=COLUMNS(B2:F2),"xxx",
    INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0)))
```

Comment: That was the problem I was having with the Index formula earlier.  There will be blank cells between, as the page will drop from google's index from time to time.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: One quick thing-- It works great, except that if all cells are empty on a row, it returns #N/A.  So, I changed the formula slightly to include an IsNA() condition: `=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0))), "xxx", INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(1,IF(B2:F2<>0,IF(B2:F2<>"",1)),0)))`

Comment: @Dexter: I posted another possible solution above. If nothing else, it's a little more human-readable

Comment: Ah, ok, I see.  I'll use it that way then.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following works if entered as an ARRAY formula (ctrl-shift-enter).

Works also if there are blank cells in the middle.

```
{=INDEX(B2:F2,1,MIN(IF(ISBLANK(B2:F2),99999,COLUMN(B2:F2))))}
```

HTH

**Edit**

This one controls the error too:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(B2:F2,1,MIN(IF(ISBLANK(B2:F2),9999,COLUMN(B2:F2))))),"xxx",
  INDEX(B2:F2,1,MIN(IF(ISBLANK(B2:F2),9999,COLUMN(B2:F2)))))}
```