# Find the relative distance of the first number in column above a cell

Tags: excel

I' m trying to find an excel formula to return the relative position of the first cell with a number value, above a specific cell in a column.
For example:

A2 (value) =1

A3 (value) = not number

A4--> Formula must return -2

Comment: Adapt this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4511710/4961700

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNUMBER(<range>)` to return an array of booleans. Multiplying that array by `ROW(<same range)` will then return an array of rows where `ISNUMBER()` is true. Wrapping that in `MAX()` should then return the max row that contains a number.

```
=MAX(ISNUMBER(A$1:A3)*ROW(A$1:A3))
```

In your scenario that would return a `1`. You can subtract your current `ROW() - 1`) to convert that into the relative position. Something like:

```
=MAX(ISNUMBER(X$1:X5)*ROW(X$1:X5)) - (ROW() - 1)
```

Probably need some extra logic to account for cases where no numbers are found, but that should be relatively straightforward.